# How to stop DIV dropping to next line?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use this code:

```
<div class="youtube" id="LcIytqkbdlo" style="width: 320px; height: 180px;"></div>
<script src="https://labnol.googlecode.com/files/youtube.js"></script>
```

with the js from here:

http://www.labnol.org/internet/light-youtube-embeds/27941/

However if I place the div twice, the second div goes to the next line. How can I make a line of videos with a margin between them?

Comment: BTW I've tried float:left but it broke the player and didn't display at all.

Comment: can you put jsfiddle.net for that?

Comment: Have you tried `display: inline-block;` ?

Comment: display: inline-block did the trick.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
<div>
  <div class="youtube" id="LcIytqkbdlo" style="width: 320px; height: 180px; float:left;"></div>
  <div class="youtube" id="LcIytqkbdlo" style="width: 320px; height: 180px;float:left;"></div>
<div>
```

i have added float left style this will not take next div to next line until div having size of window size or parent div size(width).